# Templates aren't working properly after update

Tags: ee1, ee2-upgrades

I just updated this site for a client from ExpressionEngine 1.6.3 to 2.7.2 Now the blog works fine but the individual blog entries aren't displaying.

Any ideas on where I should start to troubleshoot this?

Edit:
Sorry, now I realize that the question was way too vague. The page listing the blog entries displays fine but when I visit an individual entry, the url is wrong.

Link to the site:
http://professor-murmann.info/

Pastie of the template code:
http://pastie.org/private/6x367wh2yilbulceotf5g

Comment: I think this is way too broad or vague for anyone to be of use to you here. We need more info. Maybe start with telling us what you have tried and what else - if anything - is broken, etc. Maybe pasting, or linking to, a copy of your blog entry template, description of your URL/template structure, etc.

Comment: Is the correct name of your template that should display your individual entry "fullarticle_all_channels"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the template you should be using is fullarticle_all_weblogs as opposed to fullarticle_all_channels.

For example.

http://professor-murmann.info/index.php/weblog/fullarticle_all_weblogs/1161

vs

http://professor-murmann.info/index.php/weblog/fullarticle_all_channels/1161

Comment: Thanks John. You nailed it. Can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say the "blog works fine" if the entries aren't showing up. But did you change "exp:weblog" in your templates to "exp:channel"?

Comment: Yes, exp:weblog was changed to exp:channel in the upgrade process.